# Handling keyboard presses in a WinUI 3 application

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

I have this simple code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="MainWindow"
        x:Name="_MainWindow">
    <Grid x:Name="_WindowMainGrid">
        <Frame x:Name="_MainFrame"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      x:Class="GamePage"
      x:Name="_GamePage">
    <Grid x:Name="_PageMainGrid">
        <Image x:Name="_Image" SizeChanged="_Image_SizeChanged"/>
        <Grid x:Name="_WorkGrid">
            <!--Elements...-->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I want that in this frame, on this page, my keyboard keystrokes are processed. For this I use the following code:

```
_PageMainGrid.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    if (args.Key == VirtualKey.Q)
    {
        // Action
    }
    if (args.Key == VirtualKey.W)
    {
        // Action
    }
};
```

But that doesn't work, because it needs focus to handle keyboard presses. I tried to set it this way:

```
_PageMainGrid.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

But it always returns false and the focus is not set. Please tell me how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set **IsTabStop="True"** on the grid (in XAML code).

Edit:
It depends of course how you want your page to functioning. But I added a button with following code in the click event handler.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _PageMainGrid.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    }
```

When I tab to the button I can no longer enter any keys to the grid. Click on the button takes focus back to the grid.

Edit:
You can get all keyboard input into the Page KeyDown event. Wherever the focus is, the key events will bubble up to the page. And from there you can send the keystrokes wherever you want.
This is the easiest and safest way. And it's pretty simple.

```
    private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Page_KeyDown: " + e.Key);
    }
```

Now you have to deal with the virtual keys and keyboard layouts, but you may already know how to do that.

Edit Sep 13:
If your "_WindowMainGrid" is your top container in the window, this seems to always receive the keystrokes into it’s KeyDown. You can then send them into a function on your page. This would be the same idea as the Page_KeyDown. But it seems only to work on the highest container in the window.
Another solution that I have tested once but never used, is to use a Button as a container. Put every other control on your page into the buttons content. Button seems to receive keystrokes even if it isn’t the top-level container. To remove the buttons behavior/look, you must give it an empty style.

Edit Sep 16:
In this example I set the page into the frame content in the windows constructor. A simplification of course, but the window doesn’t have to know anything about the page more than checking for the interface at runtime. The interface is not necessary, but using it means that you can add the interface to the pages where you accept keystrokes, and the window will automatically know it is OK to call the Keystroke-function and that it exists and have the correct signature. Otherwise, if you don’t want to use the interface, you can just check if it is the type of page that you want to send keystrokes to and cast the Frame content to that type.

Interface:

```
    interface IKeystrokes
{
    public void KeyStrokes(KeyRoutedEventArgs e);
}
```

The page looks like this with the interface added and implemented function Keystrokes.

Page:

```
public sealed partial class GamePage : Page, IKeystrokes
{
    public GamePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void KeyStrokes(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("From MainGrid " + e.Key);
    }

    private void _Image_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) { }
}
```

In the window KeyDown I check if the page has the interface and call its Keystroke function if so.

```
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _MainFrame.Content = new GamePage();
    }

    private void _WindowMainGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_MainFrame.Content.GetType().GetInterface(nameof(IKeystrokes)) != null)
            ((IKeystrokes)_MainFrame.Content).KeyStrokes(e);
        Debug.WriteLine("_WindowMainGrid: " + e.Key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It really works, but there is a small problem. When I start interacting with other elements on the page, apparently the focus moves to another element and the keyboard buttons stop being processed. You have to use the tab button to return focus to the Grid and only after that they are processed again

Comment: See the edit. I also think there is a way to lock the keyboard to the grid, even if the grid don't has focus. But I'm not sure how to do it, I'll edit the answer if I find a way.

Comment: It would be very great if you could find a solution. In general, I would like to achieve such behavior that when I am on the page, keyboard presses are processed in any situation, regardless of its focus. As an option, yes, it would be possible to return the focus back to the Grid during any interaction, but it seems to me that this makes the code more complex and confusing

Comment: See the second edit. I have used the Page as the highest container on the page. But if you have all your other controls inside a grid, then the grid's KeyDown will also get all the keystrokes. But I guess that is not your case. This is actually also what Andrew is suggesting.

Comment: I tried to do as Andrew said, but for some reason it doesn’t work in my case. When I bind a handler to a Page it doesn't work at all until I set its IsTabStop property = true. But when I install it I have to return focus. Roughly speaking, it doesn’t matter where I install this handler: to the Grid or Page, it works the same for me, given the focus

Comment: I tried Andrews example and it works fine, even when my button has focus. I was doing it with a new WINUI 3 project template and as simple as possible. You have little more code I guess that is handling the Frame as well. So maybe there is something else that is the problem.

Comment: It is the grid in the Window "_WindowMainGrid" that is the problem. Without that grid it works. With the grid it works only when my button has focus. If I add a KeyDown handler  on that grid, it recieves all keyboard strokes. But if you remove that grid it works. Not very stable behavior, though.

Comment: I tried removing the Grid from the MainWindow and leaving only the Frame, but it didn’t work for me either. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong and I really have a more complex application structure. In any case, I cannot remove the Grid from the MainWindow, since there is still a custom TitleBar there. I'll figure this out somehow

Comment: @ГеоргийПопов  Have you got any updates about this issue?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT , no, I still don't know how to make it work the way I want. The only thing that saves is using IsTabStop, but this is not very convenient :( Are you facing the same problem?

Comment: @ГеоргийПопов Have you checked out the new recommendations from RolandJS?

Comment: @RolandJS, yes, thank you very much for your answer, I set the KeyDown handler in WindowMainGrid and it does handle all keys. But I haven’t figured out yet how to pass this call to the page. Because the window itself does not have access to many necessary page members

Comment: @RolandJS, now it works just fine. Thank you very much for such detailed help!

Answer (score 0):

These events might get handled. If you want to make sure you capture them, you should capture them in the `Page`.

For example:

**GamePage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public GamePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.KeyDown += (s, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Key == VirtualKey.Q)
        {
        }

        if (args.Key == VirtualKey.W)
        {
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm missing something? I repeated the code according to your example

Comment: I actually created a test app for this answer and it works. Can you try it in a new plane WinUI 3?

Comment: In the case that `KeyDown` might be handled, you can also try `PreviewKeyDown`.

Comment: I created a new project, tried both the packaged and unpackaged versions, but the keyboard buttons are not processed. But mouse buttons are processed under the same conditions. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: In my test app, I put this on the constructor. Can you place a breakpoint and make sure that the code is called?

Comment: The handler is also added in the constructor. And this code is executed. I checked it through debugging. However, the handler code itself is not called when it comes to handling keyboard presses. The mouse handler code is executed. Moreover, I tried different options. I bound events to both the Page and the Grid, in all cases the mouse is processed, but the keyboard is not. Could the problem be getting focus?

Comment: Not sure why it's not working on your side. All I did is create a plain WinUI 3 app, implement a `Page` and place the code above in the `Page`'s constructor. Have you tried subscribing KeyDown (or PreviewKeyDown) from XAML instead of C# code?

Comment: Yes, I tried to define a handler in XAML, including PreviewKeyDown, but nothing works. It is very strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255219/discussion-between-andrew-keepcoding-and--).